# Python Scikit-Learn 0.24.1 has not been built correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

I think I am having environment related issue. I have just migrated my 'admin' username to 'username' on DS220+ Synology Diskstation. I needed to run python program via ssh on a daily basis. During the migration things have broken down.

I have installed scikit-learn via:

```
sudo python3 -m pip install virtualenv
python3 -m virtualenv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install scikit-learn==0.24.1
```

and to confirm

```
pip show scikit-learn
>Name: scikit-learn
Version: 0.24.1
Summary: A set of python modules for machine learning and data mining
Home-page: http://scikit-learn.org
Author:
Author-email:
License: new BSD
Location: /volume1/homes/username/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages
Requires: joblib, numpy, scipy, threadpoolctl
Required-by:
```

I am unable to run python code as follows and the error are as shown below:

```
username@synology:~$ venv/bin/python3 /volume1/homes/username/Drive/stock/portfolio/price_updater.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/volume1/homes/username/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/__check_build/__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
    from ._check_build import check_build  # noqa
ImportError: dlopen: cannot load any more object with static TLS

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/volume1/homes/username/Drive/stock/portfolio/price_updater.py", line 6, in <module>
    from new.portbot import PortfolioBot
  File "/volume1/homes/username/Drive/stock/new/portbot.py", line 25, in <module>
    from NewStock import Stock
  File "/volume1/homes/username/Drive/stock/NewStock.py", line 17, in <module>
    from new.buyingprice import BuyingPrice
  File "/volume1/homes/username/Drive/stock/new/buyingprice.py", line 13, in <module>
    from new.pricetarget import PriceTarget
  File "/volume1/homes/username/Drive/stock/new/pricetarget.py", line 19, in <module>
    from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
  File "/volume1/homes/username/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/__init__.py", line 81, in <module>
    from . import __check_build  # noqa: F401
  File "/volume1/homes/username/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/__check_build/__init__.py", line 46, in <module>
    raise_build_error(e)
  File "/volume1/homes/username/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/__check_build/__init__.py", line 31, in raise_build_error
    raise ImportError("""%s
ImportError: dlopen: cannot load any more object with static TLS
___________________________________________________________________________
Contents of /volume1/homes/username/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/__check_build:
_check_build.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.sosetup.py                  __init__.py
__pycache__
___________________________________________________________________________
It seems that scikit-learn has not been built correctly.

If you have installed scikit-learn from source, please do not forget
to build the package before using it: run `python setup.py install` or
`make` in the source directory.

If you have used an installer, please check that it is suited for your
Python version, your operating system and your platform.
```

I know that my scikit-learn installation is fine because if I do:

```
username@Synology:~$ venv/bin/python3
Python 3.8.6 (default, Jan  4 2021, 16:11:49)
[GCC 4.9.3 20150311 (prerelease)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sklearn
>>>
```

I am able to import scikit-learn.